# I'm trying to Install Eclipse But When I Try to Run ./configure It Doesn't Work

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, software-installation, eclipse

So I am trying to install Eclipse through terminal by watching a video, but when I attempt to run `./configure` I get a message saying

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I looked around and then realized there was no configure in the eclipse folder unlike the video I was watching. The files that are showing in the eclipse folder are

```
artifacts.xml  
dropins  
eclipse.ini  
icon.xpm  
plugins 
configuration  
eclipse  
features     
p2        
readme
```

So I am wondering what I should do from here to install eclipse. I really would appreciate anyone who can help me to finish installing this program.

Thanks, Nova

Comment: http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/43936498.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't need an installation. Simply run

```
./eclipse
```

inside the folder. That's all.

---

Or create the desktop file. In my example, the Eclipse folder is located in `/opt/eclipse`

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

and add the lines below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse 
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment 
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;     
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```